# binascii.Error odd length string when reading hex string from the file

Tags: python, encryption, hex

This the line which the program is suppose to read from the file (when the user inputs the file name

```
Encrypted string: b'c0e4c042ab06829bf3ef1763d33b9671cf165356c9cef18c5c201d2e173e892e'

with open(u_input) as fp:
    read_lines = fp.readlines()
    read_message = read_lines[0].split()
    message = read_message[2]
    print("Message: %s"% message)

uncombine = binascii.unhexlify(message)
print("decrypt: %s"%uncombine)
```

Once the line is read the program is suppose to pick the hex string from the line (which is already happening) But just when I unhex the hex it gives me the error:

> binascii.Error: Odd-length string

NOTE: I have tried .strip() that doesn't help.

Comment: what does `print(len(message))` say?  Is `print(message)` what you expect?  (Inserted above the `uncombine = binsascii...` line)

Comment: @jedwards 67 characters I have tested that and when counted the characters it showed 67 characters as well. At first I thought there will be whitespaces but that wasn't the case.

Comment: And we all agree that 67 is an odd number, right?

Comment: what about `print(message.startswith("b'"))` in the same place.  You may need to copy and paste that, it's a b and a single apostrophe inside double quotes.  If it says `True`, you've written `b'<hex string>'` in your file, and can fix it by either fixing your input file, or maybe just `...unhexlify(message[2:-1])`  (I'd prefer the first alternative)

Comment: @jedwards you are right. It says TRUE. I am not too sure how can I fix it in the input file. To explain this clearly: There is a encryption program which is encrypting the string and converting it into hex using the command: 
`hex_string = binascii.hexlify(combine)` and then I am saving that string into the file. Therefore not too sure how to fix it.